# Conditional action creators in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

Is it a best practice to write conditions in action creators ? if not what are the alternative for that?

my scenario is that , i have a file uploader and depending a selection i either push the data to reducerA or reducerB.

```
return function (dispatch, getState) {
        const { selectedStage } = getState();
        if (selectedStage.stage === Constants.STAGE_CARRIER) {
            **dispatch(uploadCarrier(payload));**
        } else {
            **dispatch(uploadWeb(payload));**
        }

    };
```

Comment: It depends on where you want/need to make the decision. I see three options. All three feel legal.
1. in the action creator (as you example)
2. while connecting, check state and give an according action
3. inside component, like `this.props.stage === Constants.STAGE_CARRIER ? this.props.uploadCarrier() : this.props.uploadWeb()`

Comment: You should dispatch different actions inside your component(smart). Your action creator should not know about any differences, it only should be a plain object. All conditions you should write inside your component. It's good because your other components might use the same actions and you don't want to put there code for a specific component. For example: `addFile: (file, type) => { if (type === 'A') { dispatchProps.AddA(file) } else { dispatchProps.addB(file) } }`